# How to make the equivalent of a SAS macro with do loop in R studio?

Tags: r, loops, macros, sas

I have a bunch of SAS datasets named "haveyear" ranging from 2000-2018, i.e. `"have2000"-"have2018"`. These are stored on a local directory at `'path_to_have_data'`. Each dataset contains several variables, i.e. `var1`, `var2` and so on. I want to load these datasets and then subset them contingent on `var1 ne '0'` and also keep var1 and var2 from the original datasets. Furthermore, I want to add a new variable `year` to each of the subsets, so I can tell which year the data is from. Finally, I want to append (stack) all the new subsets into a single dataset named `appended`. For example:

Dataset `Have2017` looks like this:

```
var1 var2 var3
 0    2    5
 3    7    9
```

Dataset `Have2018` looks like this:

```
var1 var2 var3
 0    2    5
 3    7    9
```

Subset `Want2017` looks like this:

```
var1 var2 year
 3    7   2017
```

Subset `Want2018` looks like this:

```
var1 var2 year
 3    7   2018
```

The final dataset `appended` looks like this:

```
var1 var2 year
 3    7   2017
 3    7   2018
```

The following SAS script does the trick:

```
libname raw 'path_to_have_data';

%macro a;

%do &year.=2000 %to 2018;

data want&year. (keep= var1 var2);
set raw.have&year.;
where var1 ne '0';
year=&year.;
run;

%end;
%mend;
%a;

data appended;
set want:;
run;
```

Does anyone know how to achieve the same result with R Studio?

### EDIT: the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) version of the question

Here is a working version of the SAS code needed to produce the required result from the original post.

First, one needs a DATA step to create a few SAS data sets. We'll store them in the default `WORK` library instead of referencing another library on disk.

```
/* generate sample data */
 data have2000 have2001 have2002;
    input var1 var2 var3;
    cards;
    0 1 2
    1 3 5
    2 7 4
    0 9 9
    8 7 3
    ;
    run;
```

Next, we'll need a few edits to the SAS macro to make it run.

```
/* run macro from OP */
options mprint; /* shows SAS code generated by macro processor */
/* 
 * corrections / adjustments made to macro
 * 1. remove & in %do loop
 * 2. add year to keep list
 * 3. fix syntax error in where statement because var1 is numeric 
 * 4. use work library, and only process 3 years of data 
 */
%macro a;
   %do year = 2000 %to 2002;
      data want&year. (keep= var1 var2 year);
         set have&year.;
         where var1 ne 0;
         year=&year.;
      run;
   %end;
%mend;
/* run the macro */
%a;
```

The SAS option `mprint` causes SAS to write the code generated by the macro to the log. When we run the macro, a subset of the generated code for a single data set looks like this.

```
 MPRINT(A):   data want2000 (keep= var1 var2 year);
 MPRINT(A):   set have2000;
 MPRINT(A):   where var1 ne 0;
 MPRINT(A):   year=2000;
 MPRINT(A):   run;
 MPRINT(A):   data want2001 (keep= var1 var2 year);
 MPRINT(A):   set have2001;
 MPRINT(A):   where var1 ne 0;
 MPRINT(A):   year=2001;
 MPRINT(A):   run;
 MPRINT(A):   data want2002 (keep= var1 var2 year);
 MPRINT(A):   set have2002;
 MPRINT(A):   where var1 ne 0;
 MPRINT(A):   year=2002;
 MPRINT(A):   run;
```

The macro generates three SAS data steps, one for each year, including the following changes.

- Drop `var3`
- Delete rows where `var1 = 0`
- Write output to a SAS data set named `want<year>`

Finally, the code combines the data sets just created into a single SAS data set called `appended`. We'll also print the resulting data set.

```
data appended;
set want:; /* references all SAS datasets that start with "want" */
run;

proc print data = appended;
run;
```

...and the output:

[image]

Comment: Could describe in words what your script does - for non-SAS user obviously. Would also be great to see example input and expected output.

Comment: @markus - The OP has a a number of SAS datasets stored in a directory, `have2000` to `have2018`. The SAS macro reads each dataset, subsets it, adds a `year` variable, and then combines them into a single SAS data set. For example input & output, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Base R solution to the problem. The OP wants to replicate the process of a SAS macro that subsets a list of SAS data sets, raw.have2000 - raw.have2018, keeps two columns, sets a variable `year` equal to the year listed in the data set name, and joins these into a single data set.

```
# create some data

var1 <- 0:5
var2 <- 6:11
var3 <- 12:17 

raw.have2000 <- data.frame(var1,var2,var3)
raw.have2001 <- data.frame(var1,var2,var3)
raw.have2002 <- data.frame(var1,var2,var3)

years <- 2000:2002
dataList <- lapply(years,function(x){
     # create name of data set as a character object
     dsname <- paste0("raw.have",x)
     # use dsname with get() to extract data and subset first 2 variables
     ds <- subset(get(dsname),var1 !=0,select=c(var1,var2))
     ds$year <- x
     # print to have data frame returned in
     # output list 
     ds 
})
# combine data frames 
appended <- do.call(rbind,dataList)
```

...and the output, noting that the rows where `var1 = 0` have been eliminated, `var3` has been dropped, and the `year` variable has been added:

```
> appended
   var1 var2 year
2     1    7 2000
3     2    8 2000
4     3    9 2000
5     4   10 2000
6     5   11 2000
21    1    7 2001
31    2    8 2001
41    3    9 2001
51    4   10 2001
61    5   11 2001
22    1    7 2002
32    2    8 2002
42    3    9 2002
52    4   10 2002
62    5   11 2002
>
```

### Explanation

One of the major differences between SAS and R is that experienced SAS programmers use the SAS macro language to automate repetitive tasks. The macro language generates SAS code that is processed by the SAS system.

R does not have a macro language / code generator. However, one can use the `get()` function to access R objects whose names can be generated by combining various pieces of information into character objects.

Comment: @ThomasChristensen - if you're an experienced SAS programmer who is new to R, it takes a bit of effort to unlearn the SAS way of doing things. However, the effort is worth it. One can do a lot in R with very little code, as I explain in [A SAS Version of Pollutantmean](https://github.com/lgreski/datasciencectacontent/blob/master/markdown/rprog-pollutantmeanSASVersion.md).

Comment: I'm relatively experienced with data science in SAS, but I just started programming in R a few days ago. As you point out in the link, some things that are straightforward in SAS are quite complicated in R and vice versa. However, I'm convinced already that R has a lot of advantages over SAS, so I'm eager to learn it, dispite the start up difficulties :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider retrieving all needed *have* data frames in global environment using `mget` into a list of data frames. Then, iteratively run your data frame operations on each item, then row bind all items at end.

Below uses `mapply` to iterate elementwise between the *have* data frames and years 2000-2018:

```
haves_dfs <- mget(ls(pattern="have"))

# SUBSET ROWS AND COLUMNS
want_dfs <- mapply(function(df, yr) transform(subset(df, var1 != '0')[c("var1", "var2")],
                                              year = yr), 
                   have_dfs, c(2000:2018), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

final_df <- do.call(rbind, want_dfs)
```

Or with `lapply` using `get` iteratively:

```
want_dfs <- lapply(c(2000:2018), function(yr) 
               # SUBSET ROWS AND COLUMNS
               transform(subset(get(paste0("have", yr)), var1 != '0')[c("var1", "var2")],
                         year = yr)
            )

final_df <- do.call(rbind, want_dfs)
```

---

Above, might appear dense but this nested one line

```
transform(subset(df, var1 != '0')[c("var1", "var2")], year = yr)
```

Equates to the multiple step:

```
df_process <- function(df, yr) {
    # SUBSET ROWS
    df <- df[df$var1 != '0',]
    # SUBSET COLUMNS
    df <- df[c("var1", "var2")]
    # ADD NEW COLUMN
    df$year <- yr

    # RETURN FINAL
    return(df)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Parfait for also writing a great answer that does the trick! However, in your first line of code you wrote:

```
haves_dfs <- mget(ls(pattern="have"))
```

and subsequently you refered to:

```
have_dfs
```

Hence, your first line of code should have been:

```
have_dfs <- mget(ls(pattern="have"))
```

I have adjusted your answer and combined it with the dataset generating part of the answer @Len gave. Here is a fully working example of the solution:

```
var1 <- 0:5
var2 <- 6:11
var3 <- 12:17

have2000 <- data.frame(var1,var2,var3)
have2001 <- data.frame(var1,var2,var3)
have2002 <- data.frame(var1,var2,var3)

have_dfs <- mget(ls(pattern="have"))

want_dfs <- mapply(function(df, yr) transform(subset(df, var1 != '0')[c("var1", "var2")],
                                              year = yr), 
                   have_dfs, c(2000:2002), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

final_df <- do.call(rbind, want_dfs)
```

or alternatively with `lapply` using `get()`:

```
want_dfs <- lapply(c(2000:2002), function(yr) 
transform(subset(get(paste0("have", yr)), var1 != '0')[c("var1", "var2")],
            year = yr) )

final_df <- do.call(rbind, want_dfs)
```